# Conditional to move forward depending on what shell is used

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements, fish, dotfiles

I'm trying to write a `.functions` dotfile, with the purpose of loading it (`source $HOME/.functions`) in my bash, zsh and fish configuration files. I already did it with another (`.aliases`), successfully. However now I am facing a problem derived from fish not being posix-compliant.

The thing is that aliases share syntax among the three shells, but when it comes to functions fish has its own syntax (`function my_func; #code; end` instead of `function my_func { #code; }`). As an example, consider:

Fish:

```
function say_hello
    echo "hello";
end
```

Bash/Zsh:

```
say_hello() {
    echo "hello";
}
```

This disables me from just writing them in the file "as is", so I was thinking of writing a conditional such as `if [ "$0" = "bash" ] || [ "$0" = "zsh" ]; then #functions_POSIX; else #functions_fish; fi`. However, this conditional syntax is also not available in fish!

That's where I'm stuck rn. I would rather not have separate files for each shell.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you show us one of your functions whose body is the same for fish and bash? Please add it to your answer by [edit]ing. If there is no such function, then I don't see how this is possible. You could either use one file per shell, or try to automatically parse and convert one of these files in the other shells, or create one script file per function such that you can call them like regular programs (but in that case your "function" wouldn't be able to affect the parent shell anymore).

Comment: Hi @Socowi, I just added an example, as you requested. As I said, I would rather not creating separate files. Honestly I think there has to be a way... Maybe something along the lines of sourcing just a fixed amount of lines of the `.functions` file? I don't see that in `source`'s man page...

Comment: Thank you. I added an answer for your question in the title: *`Conditional to move forward depending on what shell is used`*. However, I might have been mislead by that title. Could it be that all your function bodies are polyglots and you want to define them just once instead of defining the same function twice, even if both definitions are in the same file?

Comment: I don't use fish, so I did not test the next suggestion: source an intermediate wrapper file that will check the used shell. With `bash` that file will source a normal `.functions` file. With fish something like `source <(sed -r 's/.*() {/function /; s/^}/end/' .functions)`. Looking at the answer of @Socowi, you might also need to change endtags like `s/ fi$/end/`.

Comment: @P.Mosey : Sooner or later, you will stumble over code which works differently between zsh and bash too; your problem is not specific to fish. I would separate those definitions which are syntactically different between the shells into separate files. As for functions, as long as your functions are not supposed to modify the environment of the shell they run in, consider coding them as external scripts (where you are free to choose any language you like).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @Socowi, I do not really know what you mean with your inquiry. Walter A, that seems quite interesting, I will look into it. Finally, user1934428, I think you're mistaken there. Agreed that bash and zsh are different, however AFAIK both are POSIX compliant. I have never stumbled upon code for one not working in the other one. And regarding scripts, well, that'd work but it's an overkill, and as I mentioned I want to keep things simple.

Comment: It is quite easy to write code that works in bash but not zsh, even in the default configuration (unless you call both as "sh", where they'd enable compatibility mode). E.g. zsh doesn't run word splitting on variable expansions by default, so `a="-r -i"; grep $a foo bar` means different things in both.

Answer (score 1):

The only workable answer, in my opinion, is to separate the definitions.

Even if you figure out some way to hack around the fact that fish checks the syntax for the entire file (so wherever you put a bash function definition it will give a syntax error without executing anything), this won't yield a readable file that's nice to edit. You'll just be fighting the hacks.

And function definitions can't be shared anyway, as it's not just a simple search-and-replace of `fi` to `end` - the semantics are different, e.g. a command substitution will only be split on newlines, the various special variables (`$@`) work in different ways, arrays are entirely different, etc...

That means making it a single file isn't workable or helpful, so make your functions scripts instead (if they don't modify the shell's environment) or make a wrapper around a script that does the environment changing, or just write them twice.

Comment: Hi @faho, thank you for your answer. I know I am just aiming for a workaround, which might end up being a bit clunky. I just really cherish minimalism. 

I don't want to have another dotfile or dotfiles lying around, as I already have too many for my liking. And the script option, you're right, it's the ideal one, but again, that would mean creating even more files.

I was only wondering if the fish shell people had though of this incompatibility and provided a solution (they have though of it with aliases, they are compatible). But I now think there's no way.